# phpStorm : wrong path returned by realpath function

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am using symfony and phpunit for my tests.

I had a project in foodmeup.dev directory which I copied into foodmeupnew.dev

Now, when making a call to phpunit from phpStorm command line, I've got something strange with the autoload file being looked for in the previous folder.

See the following, at line 8 it's changing dir from foodmeupnew.dev to foodmeup.dev, how can I correct this ?

```
> D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\bin\phpunit.bat -c app

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getLadybug() (previously declared in D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\raulfraile\ladybug-themes\Ladybug\Plugin\Extra\Resources\php\helpers.php:12) in D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\vendor\raulfraile\ladybug-themes\Ladybug\Plugin\Extra\Resources\php\helpers.php on line 21

Call Stack:
    0.0002     234304   1. {main}() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:0
    0.0088    1457264   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:36
    0.0088    1463816   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:99
    0.0088    1466536   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:109
    0.0132    2056112   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:575
    0.0134    2065160   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:750
    0.0136    2065352   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Fileloader.php:36
    0.0183    3407040   8. include_once('D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\bootstrap.php.cache') D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Util\Fileloader.php:52
    0.0185    3409304   9. require_once('D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\autoload.php') D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\bootstrap.php.cache:5
    0.0187    3411320  10. require('D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\vendor\autoload.php') D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\autoload.php:9
    0.0191    3424808  11. ComposerAutoloaderInit751ca4f7e73ded3907cdc8698c543ac6::getLoader() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\vendor\autoload.php:7
    0.0214    3630760  12. composerRequire751ca4f7e73ded3907cdc8698c543ac6() D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:45
```

EDIT:

I've taken the following measure to make sure foodmeup.dev was not hardcoded :
- find and replace in content of every file including hidden and system files the string 'foodmeup.dev' by 'foodmeupnew.dev'
- delete entire directory, create new one, pull git branch, run composer install, reset bootstrap.cache

same error happens again. I'm sure there might be some misconfiguration but I can find out where it's coming from. any clue ?

EDIT2

OK, I figured out that line 5 is loading phpunit configuration that contains the hardcoded 'foodmeup.dev' value.
Where does this configuration come from... that is to find out

```
> $phpunit - D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:566
============================================================================================================
array(
  [colors]        => string(4) "auto"
  [backupGlobals] => bool(false)
  [bootstrap]     => string(64) "D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\bootstrap.php.cache"
)
```

EDIT 3

Digging into it, I figured out that in file `D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:566` the realpath function applied to a relative path would render a different path.

```
var_dump($this->arguments['configuration'] . '/phpunit.xml');
```

> string(15) "app/phpunit.xml"

```
var_dump(realpath($this->arguments['configuration'] . '/phpunit.xml'));
```

> > realpath($this->arguments['configuration'] . '/phpunit.xml') - D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeupnew.dev\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\Command.php:529
> >     ================================================================================================================================================================ string(56) "D:\Divers\Programmation\Web\foodmeup.dev\app\phpunit.xml"

How can that be that the realpath function renders a path with foodmeup.dev when the call is made from a file located in the foodmeupnew.dev directory ?

EDIT 4:

I figured out this is a phpStorm issue. there must be a global variable which sets the dir for php function. If I run the command from an external command line, the error does not arise

Comment: I don't see what `line 8` has to do with anything; the error is `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getLadybug() (previously declared in ... helpers.php ... Plugin\Extra\Resources\php\helpers.php) on line 21`

Comment: well, I'm running php unit in the foodmeupnew.dev directory and it is switching somehow to another directory. This obviously leads to an error later on because it's requiring a file from a different project

Comment: My guess would be something is hardcorded to use the `foodmeup.dev` path, or it's cached somewhere.

Comment: well, see my edit, indeed, the value is a phpunit parameter. But i'm still investigating where it's set

Comment: configuration file phpunit.xml?

Comment: you need to run composer install to rerun the initialisation scripts, these will set the paths correctly as far as I know

Comment: composer install did not work. @NawfalSerrar : there is no reference to the path in this file... I have the impression it's a default configuration. By the way, I don't understand why some want to close this issue...

Comment: its the default configuration file usually inside app folder.

Comment: I've added some data: this is the realpath function that renders the dir, and it renders the wrong one despite being called from a file located in the right directory...

Comment: search also in the source folder for foodmeup.dev see where it has been hardcoded

Comment: already done it, I can't find no reference for it. as I said just before, it seems to be the realpath function that renders the wrong directory. so it's not hardcoded... no ?

Comment: I think it's a phpStorm global config because when I run the command from a external command line, the problem does not arise, the realpath function does return the correct path